# Barcode not showing on rails [Barby Gem]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, png, barcode

## Gems used

```
Ruby '1.9.3'

Rails '3.2.11'

Bbarby', '~> 0.5.1'

Chunky_png', '~> 1.3.0'
```

## Application Helper

```
require 'barby'
require 'barby/barcode/code_128'
require 'barby/barcode/ean_13'
require 'barby/outputter/png_outputter'
require 'barby/outputter/ascii_outputter'

require 'chunky_png'
```

## Controller

```
barcode = Barby::Code128B.new('The noise of mankind has become too much')

File.open('code128b.png', 'w'){|f|
f.write barcode.to_png(:height => 20, :margin => 5)
}
```

## View

```
<%= image_tag("code128b.png") %>
```

The pages renders but not the barcode:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please find the link for detailed bar code implementation :

> http://blog.andolasoft.com/2012/11/how-to-generate-barcode-using-barby-gem-in-rails-2-3-8.html

Comment: Hi Vinod, I have already install gem 'barby', '~> 0.5.1' AND gem 'chunky_png', '~> 1.3.0'. Do I need to install as well 'barby-chunky_png', 'png' AND 'RubyInline'?

Comment: If I include barby gems in config/environment.rb I get config/environment.rb:8:in `<top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `config' for main:Object (NameError)

Comment: The link which i have given related to rails 2.3.8 If you are using rails 3+ then you need to change the as per that.                                                                http://house9.blogspot.in/2011/10/generating-barcodes-with-ruby-   and-rails.html                                                                                                                          Finally using img tag you can display barcode.

Answer (score 0):

```
File.open('code128b.png', 'w'){|f|
  f.write barcode.to_png(:height => 20, :margin => 5)
}
```

this is create file "code128b.png" in your root app path, and `<%= image_tag("code128b.png") %>` call image from assets / public

why you not upload your barcode into cloudinary and save it as url into your db :)